# Calling a delphi dll with a variant type parameter from c#

Tags: c#, delphi, dll

I have a delphi dll with this function:

```
function writeRate(data: variant):Double ; stdcall;
```

I used this method for call the function from c#:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate double WriteRate(object data);
protected void UpdateRateChannel(string myData)
{   
    IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");

    IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "writeRate");
    WriteRate writeRate = (WriteRate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(WriteRate ));


    double response = writeRate(myData);

    bool result = NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(pDll);
}
```

but I getting this exception:

```
PInvokeStackImbalance was detected
```

How do I call the dll? I supposed that the issue is in the variant type.
thanks!

Comment: May I ask why you don't use the "usual" PInvoke-way of importing the function, like `[DllImport("mydll.dll")]private static extern ...`?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar If you want runtime control over the location of the DLL, this is the way to do it.

Comment: Ah! Great - didn't know you could do it like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`stdcall` in Delphi code matches [`CallingConvention.StdCall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#. You should fix your delegate definition.

Answer (score 4):

If the Delphi function is declared as being `stdcall`, why would you declare it in C# as `cdecl`?

This is the cause of the stack imbalance. Change your C# declaration to use the `stdcall` convention to match the Delphi declaration.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private delegate double WriteRate(object data);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Variant in C# is probably not compatible with the normal Variant in Delphi. Use Delphi's OleVariant instead.

Comment: This can't be it. The error is `PInvokeStackImbalance was detected`, which would be caused by a mismatched calling convention.

Comment: In that case, my answer is not to the current, but to the next question. :)